# Moving file descriptors in zsh

Tags: zsh, file-descriptors

The construction `ls 3>&2 2>&1 1>&3-` in `zsh` does not behave in a manner consistent with `ksh`/`bash` or with more limited shells like `dash` that don't support moving file descriptor at all. Instead of emitting the directory contents on standard error or complaining about an invalid file descriptor number it prints nothing. What does moving a file descriptor mean/do in `zsh`? I've only tested the various shells on OS X so far (using the most recent release installed through homebrew).

First we set up a temporary folder

```
$ mkdir /tmp/foo
$ cd /tmp/foo
$ touch a
$ touch b
```

Then we run `ls 3>&2 2>&1 1>&3-` with `bash` and `ksh`, which both support moving file descriptors.

```
$ bash -c 'ls 3>&2 2>&1 1>&3-'
a       b

$ bash --version | head -n 1
GNU bash, version 4.4.5(1)-release (x86_64-apple-darwin15.6.0)
```

`ksh` behaves similarly

```
$ ksh -c 'ls 3>&2 2>&1 1>&3-'
a       b

$ ksh --version
version         sh (AT&T Research) 93u+ 2012-08-01
```

`dash` is an example of a shell that does not support this syntax. It interprets `1>&3-` as a badly formatted duplication.

```
$ dash -c 'ls 3>&2 2>&1 1>&3-'
```

dash: 1: Syntax error: Bad fd number

`zsh`, bizarrely, prints nothing.

```
$ echo -n '<'; zsh -c 'ls 3>&2 2>&1 1>&3-'; echo '>'
<>

$  zsh --version
zsh 5.2 (x86_64-apple-darwin15.4.0)
```

Is `zsh` performing the underlying dups and closes in a different order than `bash` and `ksh` are? Does it have a bug in its implementation of this feature?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`zsh` does not support moving file descriptor syntax like `bash` or `ksh`. So `1>&3-` means redirect both standard output and standard error to file named `3-`:

```
$ echo -n '<'; zsh -c 'ls 3>&2 2>&1 1>&3-'; echo '>'
<>
$ ls
3- a b
```

For achieving the same moving file descriptor behavior like `bash` and `ksh`, in any POSIX shell:

```
sh -c 'ls 3>&2 2>&1 3>&1 3>&-'
```

That's what `1>&3-` in `bash` and `ksh` does internally, duplicated file descriptor 3 to file descriptor 1 then close file descriptor 3.

Comment: I completely missed that the file `3-` was created and didn't think to check for it. That's weird though. `zsh` supports the `csh` (and `bash`) syntax `>& file`, but `1>&<some file name>` doesn't have a reasonable interpretation. I wonder why `zsh` accepts `1>&some_file_name` at all.

Comment: @GregoryNisbet: `1>&filename` works well in `zsh`